# push array in nested Object using mongodb

Tags: mongodb-query

I would like to update a document by pushing inside nested object :

the layout of the document is the following :

```
{
   "id": 456,
   "nickname": "xxx",
   "pf": {
        "id": 123,
        "acc": [
            {
                "accid": 1494235749,
                "status": "New",
                "accnbr": 12345,
                "cyc": [
                   {
                    "cycid": 1494404053,
                    "active": true,
                    "status": "New",
                    "name": "QST192017",
                    "det" : [
                       {
                          "dcycid": 2422,
                          "status": "First"
                       }
                     ]
                   }
                 ],

            },
            {
                "accid": 1494403399,
                "status": "New",
                "accnbr": 915177,
                "cyc": [
                  {
                    "cycleid": 1494406299,
                    "active": true,
                    "status": "Closed",
                    "name": "QSL342014",
                    "det" : [
                       {
                          "dcycid": 2423,
                          "status": "First"
                       }
                     ]
                  }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
 }
```

As I said I would like to push an object inside this structure and here is what I have tried to do :

```
db.getCollection('fxh').updateOne({"id": 456, "pf.acc.accid" : 1494235749, "pf.acc.cyc.cycid": 1494404053 },{  $push : {"pf.acc.$.cyc.x.detail":  { dcycid: 123461, status: "test"}}})
```

the first $ is for acc but I need to specify the index of cyc .
Any Idea how to do it ?

Remarque in my query I have 3 'where'

1 - id

2 - pf.acc.accid

3 - pf.acc.cyc.cycid

Answer (score 0):

According to description as mentioned in above question please try executing following update operation in MongoDB shell.

```
db.fxh.update({
            id: 456,
            'pf.acc': {
                $elemMatch: {
                    accid: 1494235749,
                    cyc: {
                        $elemMatch: {
                            cycid: 1494404053
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        {
            $push: {
                'pf.acc.$.cyc': {
                    'detail': {
                        dcycid: 123461,
                        status: "test"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: it 's not the wanted result, it's create a new cyc with detail but what I want is to push de detail inside cycid = 1494404053.

Comment: And when I use this :   db.getCollection('fxh').updateOne({"userid" : 1496513894, "pf.acc" : { $elemMatch :{ "accid" : 1496720246, cyc : { $elemMatch : { "cycid" : 12345 }}}}} ,{ $push: { "pf.acc.$.cyc.1.detail" : { dcycleid: 9999, status: "test2"}}})  , it works.   Now  how to replace the $push : { pf.acc.$.cyc.1.detail.... }  BY   $push : {pf.acc.$.cyc.X.detail.....}  X= index of cyc ?

Comment: I just noticed that open ticket has been opened for $ positional operator in multiple nested array. work around is necessary for now . my first question is  how to get the index of array  ?